# Using bump functions to create desired function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\lambda \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy
$$
\begin{cases}
\lambda(x) = 0, &\text{if $x \leq 0$} \\
\lambda(x) > 1 &\text{if $x > 1$}\\
\lambda''(x) \geq 100\lambda'(x)  &\text{for all $x$}\\
\lambda''(x) > 0  &\text{if  $x > 0$}\\
\lambda'(x) > 100 &\text{if $\lambda(x) > 1/2$}. 
\end{cases}
$$

The paper I am reading says "such a function obviously exists."  Why is this obvious?  It looks like we will have to construct bump functions.  In my previous classes, whenever we dealt with a bump function, the only specification we put on the bump function was its support.  When we construct bump functions, can we specify restrictions on the first and second derivatives?  Is there a general procedure for problems like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a nondecreasing function $\zeta\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. 
$x\leq0\Rightarrow\zeta(x)=0$, $x>0\Rightarrow\zeta(x)>0$, $\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\geq\frac{1}{2}$.

Put $f(x):=\zeta(x)e^{100x}$, $\lambda(x):=\int_0^xf(t)dt$.

Then, it is clear that $x\leq0\Rightarrow\lambda(x)=0$.

If $x>1$, then $\lambda(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 e^{100t}dt>1$.

$\lambda''(x)=f'(x)=100\zeta(x)e^{100x}+\zeta'(x)e^{100x}\geq100f(x)=100\lambda'(x)$.

and so on since $e>2$.

Comment: Can you explain how you are verifying the last property in more detail?

Comment: $\lambda'(x)=f(x)=\zeta(x)e^{100x}$. If $x>\frac{1}{2}$, then $\lambda'(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}e^{100x} \geq \frac{1}{2}e^{100 \cdot \frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}e^{50}>\frac{1}{2}$ since $\zeta$ is nondecreasing.